# Hauppauge quadHD fails with PCI passthrough on Dell R710

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Dell R710 running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS as a KVM host. I have a Hauppauge WinTV quadHD tuner card installed in one of the PCI slots. I have a guest VM installed to act as a media center (same OS), to which I want to give direct access to the tuner.

I have virtualization extensions turned on in BIOS and IOMMU enabled. I've checked that the tuner seems to inhabit its own IOMMU group. In fact, the tuner does appear in the guest as you would expect, using this config in libvirt.

```
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x0a' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x09' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
```

The **problem** is that the guest accessing the device (scanning or viewing channels) has repeatedly demonstrated an unfortunate ability to take down not only the guest, but the entire host. It's not always immediate... sometimes it works for minutes or even days before failing.

When things go south, there's no kernel panic or other log event that I've discovered.* One minute everything is running, the next the whole box is rebooting.

* The RAC log gives only this hopelessly vague error, each time this event occurs:

```
Wed Jul 25 2018 15:53:23    A bus fatal error was detected on a component at slot 3.
```

Googling around surfaces basic troubleshooting steps like reseating the card (done), updating firmware (infeasible), or changing slots (done). None of these have thus far made a difference.

I don't even know who, if anyone, this could be escalated too. Is it a kernel issue? Device driver? Hardware bug?

If anyone has experienced similar faults, is there a way I can get a trace of some sort that I could escalate to the appropriate developers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the ppa as directed on the hauppauge dot com support pages??
http://www.hauppauge.com/pages/support/support_linux.html
PPA installation instructions for TV tuner driver on Ubuntu

Open Terminal in Ubuntu The easiest way to open terminal is to right click on desktop and select Open Terminal. You can also click Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard.

In Terminal, type the following or copy and paste the following lines, one by one, then click enter.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:b-rad/kernel+mediatree+hauppauge

After this first line, click enter when prompted to add this PPA.

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install linux-image-mediatree

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-mediatree

Note: if you are using a Hauppauge DVB TV tuner in Europe or Australia/New Zealand, please also install the TV firmware:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-hauppauge
```

Close Terminal and restart your computer.

You can now connect your Hauppauge WinTV TV tuner to your computer and it should be available for use by your Linux TV watching application.

Watch the PPA installation video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rMYICzKS0k&feature=youtu.be